# not able to move my range slector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

i am not able to move the range slector...
I am trying to use chart js library and build range selector.. i have iuncluded all library.. but still range selector not showing up... can you guys tell me why its not showing up... proving my fiddle below... its nopt workimg for this code..

http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Configure_RangeSelector?version=13_2

fiddle not working
http://jsfiddle.net/v5LTM/2/

```
var clientWidth = $('#rangeSelectorContainer').width();
$("#rangeSelectorContainer").dxRangeSelector({
    size: {
       height: (clientWidth - 2*65) / 4 + 20+30
    },
    scale: {
        //...
        placeholderHeight: 20
    },
    sliderMarker: {
        placeholderSize: {
            width: 65,
            height: 30
        }
    },
    margin: {
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a dataSource or startValue, endValue like in the demo.
jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/v5LTM/3/

With DataSource:

```
dataSource: [
    {arg: 0},
    {arg: 1},
    {arg: 2},
    {arg: 3}
],
```

With startValue/endValue:

```
scale: {
    //...
    startValue: 10,
    endValue: 20,
    placeholderHeight: 20
},
```